# How do I scale evenly aligned text along the x-axis with ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-text

I need to plot lots of scaled, neat text in ggplot. The difficulty is in scaling the x coordinate. I've tried various scaling functions (see below), but I can't align the text neatly. For example:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(stringr)

scaleX <- function(x) cumsum(map_dbl(x, nchar)) - map_dbl(x, nchar)

df <- tibble(
  sentences = c("This is a short sentence",
        "This is a longer sentences with more words",
        "A third sentence"),
  y = 3:1) %>% 
     mutate(words = str_split(sentences, " "),
            x = map(words, ~scaleX(.))) %>% 
     unnest() %>% 
     mutate(wordFill = ifelse(str_detect(words, "a|b|c|d|e"),  TRUE, FALSE))

ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_text(aes(label = words, color = wordFill))
```

[image]

How can I scale the words so they're evenly aligned?

Comment: Will `geom_text(aes(label = words, color = wordFill), check_overlap = TRUE)` be good enough?

Comment: Thanks @AndreyKolyadin, that's an improvement, but the distance between the words still fluctuates.